# Run C application and wait for its death

Tags: node.js

I have a C application that connects to my NodeJS server via TCP and they communicate with each other for a long time. When I run my application myself, everything is fine but when NodeJS runs my application, it suddenly stops after getting second TCP message.

```
execFile("~/workspace/mngClient/mngClient.out", ["1"], {}, function(error, stdout, stderr) { console.log("process died")});
```

and this is how my tcp server looks like

```
const net = require("net");
const server = net.createServer();
  server.listen(global.TCP_LISTEN_PORT, global.TCP_HOST_IP, () => {
    console.log("TCP Server is running on port " + global.TCP_LISTEN_PORT);
  });
```

Do you know what's the problem? `execFile` actually waits for the process but when it sends a data via TCP, it terminates.

Comment: maybe you can show the C code.  Maybe the C program has an exception?  You can try using node-pty, the environment may be more similar than with execFile.

Comment: @JasonLivesay The C application has 2k lines but if it had an exception, it would happen when I run it from console. When I run it from console, everything is fine but when node runs it dies. Sorry it's very weird situation. Probably no one can help with these information. I just thought that maybe there is a problem with execFile. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: For me `execFile` fails with an `ENOENT` error when given a program path that depends on `~`, because `~` is a shell metacharacter. In any case, do us all a favour and change your `execFile` callback function to at least write its `error` argument to `console.log`.  Preferably write the `stderr` argument too in case there's something helpful there.  Also, `msgClient.out` is an awfully strange name for a program.

Comment: @ottomeister changed the name for sharing it here Einstein